# Google Drive API downloadFile getIo Error

Tags: download, google-drive-api

I want to create a gDrive App.
I can get downloadUrl
(like as string 'https://doc-0k-68-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/gf6salc3nfs5me1dnqgnp4crl90gg593/21kfelc8h3l1qvkgskqacnee2pqjt5es/1343484000000/14678698184812381901/14678698184812381901/0B95t2gVGbZ61Sk0yNlY5TTZObUU?h=16653014193614665626&e=download&gd=true' (length=251))

But i can't download via this link.
I guess, must some auth.

i try this functions, i take [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v1/reference/files/get)

```
function downloadFile($service, $file) {
  $downloadUrl = $file->getDownloadUrl();
  if ($downloadUrl) {
    $request = new apiHttpRequest($downloadUrl, 'GET', null, null);
    $httpRequest = $service->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($request);
    if ($httpRequest->getResponseHttpCode() == 200) {
      return $httpRequest->getResponseBody();
    } else {
      // An error occurred.
      return null;
    }
  } else {
    // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
    return null;
  }
}
```

i take an error

**Call to undefined method apiDriveService::getIo() in ....**

please help me. i can't found anywhere.

```
object(apiHttpRequest)[18]
  protected 'url' => string 'https://doc-0k-68-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/gf6salc3nfs5me1dnqgnp4crl90gg593/900384ep39btqvj6j91ssm11lvom8r09/1343635200000/14678698184812381901/14678698184812381901/0B95t2gVGbZ61Sk0yNlY5TTZObUU?h=16653014193614665626&e=download&gd=true&key=AIzaSyA1qi-3-tqpyzxAXhy5c9_EkVGFNsRZ9Fw' (length=295)
  protected 'requestMethod' => string 'GET' (length=3)
  protected 'requestHeaders' => 
    array (size=1)
      'authorization' => string 'Bearer ya29.AHES6ZTgpamuF6g35HuLj2PW_KH06yZhLLNdNLF_MgaiFGLp' (length=60)
  protected 'postBody' => null
  protected 'userAgent' => string 'Tahribat google-api-php-client/0.5.0' (length=36)
  protected 'responseHttpCode' => int 404
  protected 'responseHeaders' => 
    array (size=10)
      'server' => string 'HTTP Upload Server Built on Jul 25 2012 10:54:42 (1343238882)' (length=61)
      'access-control-allow-origin' => string '*' (length=1)
      'access-control-allow-credentials' => string 'false' (length=5)
      'access-control-allow-headers' => string 'authorization' (length=13)
      'access-control-allow-methods' => string 'GET,OPTIONS' (length=11)
      'date' => string 'Mon, 30 Jul 2012 08:01:31 GMT' (length=29)
      'expires' => string 'Mon, 30 Jul 2012 08:01:31 GMT' (length=29)
      'cache-control' => string 'private, max-age=0' (length=18)
      'content-length' => string '0' (length=1)
      'content-type' => string 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' (length=24)
  protected 'responseBody' => boolean false
  public 'accessKey' => null
```

///////

```
object(DriveFile)[15]
  public 'mimeType' => string 'application/rar' (length=15)
  public 'thumbnailLink' => null
  protected '__labelsType' => string 'DriveFileLabels' (length=15)
  protected '__labelsDataType' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'labels' => 
    object(DriveFileLabels)[16]
      public 'restricted' => boolean false
      public 'hidden' => boolean false
      public 'viewed' => boolean false
      public 'starred' => boolean false
      public 'trashed' => boolean false
  protected '__indexableTextType' => string 'DriveFileIndexableText' (length=22)
  protected '__indexableTextDataType' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'indexableText' => null
  public 'etag' => string '"WtRjAPZWbDA7_fkFjc5ojsEvE7I/MTM0MzM1NDI2OTYwMA"' (length=48)
  public 'lastModifyingUserName' => string 'Pskptbt6' (length=8)
  public 'writersCanShare' => boolean true
  public 'id' => string '0By790Jqkq9pLRDRuUFZ3UWVxdGs' (length=28)
  public 'title' => string '1caec72e95949a693dc0e95eeaeb2a9e.rar' (length=36)
  public 'ownerNames' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'Pskptbt6' (length=8)
  public 'sharedWithMeDate' => null
  public 'lastViewedByMeDate' => null
  protected '__parentsType' => string 'ParentReference' (length=15)
  protected '__parentsDataType' => string 'array' (length=5)
  public 'parents' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'exportLinks' => null
  public 'originalFilename' => string 'Web Elements.rar' (length=16)
  public 'description' => null
  public 'editable' => boolean false
  public 'kind' => string 'drive#file' (length=10)
  public 'quotaBytesUsed' => string '30249130' (length=8)
  public 'fileSize' => string '30249130' (length=8)
  public 'createdDate' => string '2012-07-27T01:55:50.169Z' (length=24)
  public 'md5Checksum' => string '595182e10bcc986cc8dcc41a6e945019' (length=32)
  public 'embedLink' => null
  public 'alternateLink' => string 'https://docs.google.com/file/d/0By790Jqkq9pLRDRuUFZ3UWVxdGs/edit' (length=64)
  public 'permissionsLink' => null
  public 'modifiedByMeDate' => null
  public 'downloadUrl' => string 'https://doc-04-5s-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/gf6salc3nfs5me1dnqgnp4crl90gg593/t1ucp1ub6sdcgk7hdatj1it5m5ntoodh/1343635200000/13117762293604295629/14678698184812381901/0By790Jqkq9pLRDRuUFZ3UWVxdGs?h=16653014193614665626&e=download&gd=true' (length=251)
  protected '__userPermissionType' => string 'Permission' (length=10)
  protected '__userPermissionDataType' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'userPermission' => 
    object(Permission)[17]
      public 'withLink' => null
      public 'kind' => string 'drive#permission' (length=16)
      public 'name' => null
      public 'value' => null
      public 'id' => string 'me' (length=2)
      public 'authKey' => null
      public 'etag' => string '"WtRjAPZWbDA7_fkFjc5ojsEvE7I/dLmoyrW_nZG7qLX6EhuNvVbQIq0"' (length=57)
      public 'role' => string 'reader' (length=6)
      public 'photoLink' => null
      public 'type' => string 'user' (length=4)
      public 'additionalRoles' => null
      public 'selfLink' => string 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0By790Jqkq9pLRDRuUFZ3UWVxdGs/permissions/me' (length=85)
  public 'fileExtension' => string 'rar' (length=3)
  public 'selfLink' => string 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0By790Jqkq9pLRDRuUFZ3UWVxdGs' (length=70)
  public 'modifiedDate' => string '2012-07-27T01:57:49.600Z' (length=24)
  public 'webContentLink' => string 'https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0By790Jqkq9pLRDRuUFZ3UWVxdGs&export=download' (length=74)
```

actually i just want to like this site.

http://www.gdriveurl.com/

but, just i create automatically in my website each link.

Answer (score 8):

I installed the latest PHP Client Library and none of the suggested edits above work.

Original code

```
 $httpRequest = $service->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($request);
 Fatal error: Call to undefined method Google_Service_Drive::getIo()
```

First Suggested Change:

```
$httpRequest = apiClient::$io->authenticatedRequest($request);
Fatal error: Class 'apiClient' not found in ...../Drive/auth.php
```

Second Suggested Change:

```
$httpRequest = Google_Client::$io->authenticatedRequest($request);
Fatal error: Cannot access private property Google_Client::$io in .../Drive/auth.php
```

I found "authenticatedRequest($request);" in -  src/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php

```
 public function authenticatedRequest(Google_Http_Request $request)
  {
    $request = $this->sign($request);
    return $this->client->getIo()->makeRequest($request);
  }
```

so I change the call to:

```
 $httpRequest = Google_Auth_OAuth2::authenticatedRequest($request);
```

but it returns the error:

Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

Finally found the solution and here is the full code:

```
function downloadFile($service, $downloadUrl,$client) {

if ($downloadUrl) {
  $request = new Google_Http_Request($downloadUrl, 'GET', null, null);

  $SignhttpRequest = $client->getAuth()->sign($request);
  $httpRequest = $client->getIo()->makeRequest($SignhttpRequest);

  if ($httpRequest->getResponseHttpCode() == 200) {
    return $httpRequest->getResponseBody();
  } else {
  // An error occurred.
    return null;
  }
 } else {
  // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
   return null;
 }
}
```

Comment: I found the solution by using:

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
 $httpRequest = $service->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($request);
```

by:

```
 $httpRequest = apiClient::$io->authenticatedRequest($request);
```

I had myself the error and after, by changing the line, I didn't have a problem anymore.

$service apparently is concerning apiClient and not apiDriveService.

Comment: thanks for answer
but now i take another error.

protected 'responseHttpCode' => int 404 while downloadFile

but i can read file.

Comment: I didn't encountered this error, so, I can't help you on this but just to be sure: is the user connected to Drive? I think it would be helpful if you can put a print_r of $file and $httpRequest

Comment: Your url in apiHttprequest is different from the download Url in $file. I have two explanations: or you didn't put the right stuff or there is a mistake somewhere. Did you try with a file that isn't a .rar one? Or are you changing the URL along the way?

Comment: i create same account google drive and google api. 
i connect same account.
i checked file is there.

Comment: It doesn't change the fact that your two urls are different, perhaps it is that that is blocking you. Apart that, I can't see any other things that could block you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$request = new Google_HttpRequest($downloadUrl, 'GET', null, null);
$httpRequest = Google_Client::$io->authenticatedRequest($request);
```

for new library google-api-php-client-0.6.0.tar.gz